Роутинг Nuxt js 3
Имеется проект на Nuxt 3. Вопрос по роутингу.
Есть URL:
/clients/[ID]/info
/clients/[ID]/cars

и т.д.
Структура в папке следующая:
/pages/clients/[id]/[page]/index.vue

В index.vue подгружаются необходимые компоненты resolveComponent.
Всё работает нормально, пока я не пытаются открыть ссылку вида:
/clients/[ID]/cars/add

Получается 404 ошибку.
Как можно сделать обработку дополнительного slug в index.vue?

А где вы взяли "add"? У вас нет такого файла, либо директории. Создайте файл add.vue в директории cars.

/pages/clients/[id]/[...page]/index.vue - page станет массивом.
/pages/clients/[id]/[page]/[...operator].vue - или так. Но это уже не индекс.

Супер. Сработало. Спасибо!

Галочку ставьте тогда
